# How can one use scipy odeint to obtain multiple solutions?

Tags: scipy, ode, odeint

I am learning how to use `odeint` in `Scipy` to solve ODEs. Now I am trying to solve Schrodinger equation with a semi-infinite potential well:

```
V(x) = -v (x<0)
V(x) = 0 (x>0)
v > 0
-f''(x)/2 +V(x)f(x) = energy*f(x)
-v < energy < 0
```

So the exact solution should be

```
C1*sin(x)+C2*cos(x) (x<0)
C3*exp(x)+C4*exp(-x) (x>0)
```

I set a starting point in the x<0 region (given `f(x0),f'(x0),x0<0`), but the solution I obtained is always exp(x) in x>0 region. But exp(-x) is more meaningful in physics. How can I get this solution by using `odeint`?

Comment: That is not the exact solution. Also, try to first understand the difference between initial value problems, boundary value problems, and eigenvalue problems, and decide which one you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think it is the exact solution with some coefficients neglected. As stated, I would like to solve a initial value problem, and to compare the exact solution with the result of `odeint`.

Comment: `odeint` gives you the solution to the initial value problem. The solution to the initial value problem is unique, and given by `odeint`, and indeed it should be exponentially growing for most initial values. So you are not trying to solve an initial value problem here.

Comment: You are either trying to solve a boundary value problem or an eigenvalue problem, and I'd recommend googling to find methods how to deal with those.

Comment: OK, you solved my problem: Most initial values gives non-zero C3, and I checked my program and found that I didn't use an initial value that gives C3=0 because of a typo. Now I can get a solution with exp(-x) component only with `odeint`. If you would like to copy this part of your comments to the answer I will be glad to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

SciPy's odeint solves ODEs as you remark, but the Schroedinger equation is a PDE (partial differential equation). You could discretize the spatial coordinate and treat it as a system of coupled ODEs, but the usual approach is then to find the eigenbasis of solutions by solving the corresponding eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Yes it is PDE, but this is a 1-D system so there is only one variable, which means we can treat it like ODE.